# Как задать data атрибут?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Вот так задаю в jsx, но атрибуты не задаются.

```
  <div
            data-id={item.id}
            dataId={item.id}
          >
```

В проекте используется версия 15.4.1, обновить нет возможности.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый способ добавления дата атрибутов в старых версия React (<16)

Внутри жизненного цикла **componentDidMount** в классовых компонентах

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  const el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.test);
  el.setAttribute('test-attribute', 'test value');
}
```

Второй способ работает везде и проще применить. [**Codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-wind-9uff0) `v15.4.1.`

```
function App() {
  const testAttr = {'data-attr': 'value'}
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1  {...testAttr }>zazu</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Реакт поддерживает `data-` аттрибуты:

> React supports all data-* and aria-* attributes as well as every attribute in the following lists. [Мануал](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html#supported-attributes)

Пример в 15 версии:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div data-hello="hello">
        <h1 aria-hidden={true}>Hello, world1</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.0.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

[image: Аттрибут добавляется в 15 версии]

Comment: У меня так не работает. Версия 15.4.1

Answer (score 0):

видимо в атрибуты нельзя кидать тип данных number, ибо у меня

```
  <span className={isBuying ? '' : 'active'} data-action="sell" onClick={changeAction}>
```

data-action="sell" -- работает